# Diamond Shape but in horizontal

Tags: c++

hi can you help me to turn this into like this[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdWpa.png)

this is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int i,j,r;
    cout << "\n\n Display the pattern like a diamond:\n";
    cout << "----------------------------------------\n";
    cout << " Input number of rows (half of the diamond): ";
    cin >> r;
   for(i=0;i<=r;i++)
   {
     for(j=1;j<=r-i;j++)
     cout<<" ";
     for(j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
       cout<<"*";
     cout<<endl;
   }
   for(i=r-1;i>=1;i--)
   {
     for(j=1;j<=r-i;j++)
     cout<<" ";
     for(j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
       cout<<"*";
     cout<<endl;;
   }
}
```

Here, the purpose is to achieve a star pattern which diverges from the first row, reaches its maxima at the mid and again converges back to one at the end with an increment of 2 stars per row.

So for example for input: 3 it should be:

```
   *
 * * *
   *
```

for input: 4 it should be:

```
   *
 * * *
 * * *
   *
```

for input 5, it should be:

```
         *
       * * *
     * * * * *
       * * *
         *
```

Comment: Please provide the desired output as text not as picture of text. Doing so might actually give you the answer you need....

Comment: ... especially if you also give your current output also as text, instead of not at all. At least if you manage to describe the difference of the two outputs in prose.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What is wrong with if statements, exactly?

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        int r;
        cout << "\n\n Display the pattern like a diamond:\n";
        cout << "----------------------------------------\n";
        cout << " Input number of rows: ";
        cin >> r;
        cout << "\n";
        for(int i=1; i <= floor(r/2) + 1;i++)
        {
            for (int j = floor(r/2); j >= i; j--)
                cout << "    ";
            for (int j = 1; j <= i*2-1; j++)
                cout << "*   ";
            cout<<endl;
        }
        
        for(int i=floor(r/2);i>=1;i--)
        {
            for (int j = floor(r/2); j >= i; j--)
                cout << "    ";
            for(int j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
                cout<<"*   ";
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }




 Display the pattern like a diamond:
----------------------------------------
 Input number of rows: 9
                *   
            *   *   *   
        *   *   *   *   *   
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   
        *   *   *   *   *   
            *   *   *   
                *
```